# Why am I getting (object value omitted) when trying to find attribute of a node?

Tags: php, dom

I have an HTML file and am trying to use DOM to find the `id` attribute of all `<h2>` elements:

```
$html = new DOMDocument;
$html->loadHTML($file);
$headings = $html->getElementsByTagName('h2');
```

Which as expected returns a `DOMNodeList` with a count equal to the number of headings in my document.  When I iterate through this and try to explore the data returned through `var_dump` or `print_r` I get a (object value omitted) error for the list of attributes however:

```
object(DOMElement)#10 (18) {
  ["tagName"]=&gt;
  string(2) "h2"
  ["schemaTypeInfo"]=&gt;
  NULL
  ["nodeName"]=&gt;
  string(2) "h2"
  ["nodeValue"]=&gt;
  string(10) "What next?"
  ["nodeType"]=&gt;
  int(1)
  ["parentNode"]=&gt;
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["childNodes"]=&gt;
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["firstChild"]=&gt;
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["lastChild"]=&gt;
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["previousSibling"]=&gt;
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["nextSibling"]=&gt;
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["attributes"]=&gt;
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["ownerDocument"]=&gt;
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["namespaceURI"]=&gt;
  NULL
  ["prefix"]=&gt;
  string(0) ""
  ["localName"]=&gt;
  string(2) "h2"
  ["baseURI"]=&gt;
  NULL
  ["textContent"]=&gt;
  string(10) "What next?"
}
```

Why is this and why can't I see the number of attributes, or why isn't a `DOMNamedNodeMap` being returned as [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.attributes) says it should be?

I've tried using an xPath rather than the `getElementsByTagName` function, but have the same problem.

How do I retrieve the attributes? I can't see a method to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst the documentation states that

- `getElementsByTagName` returns a `DOMNodeList` ([getElementsByTagName](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php))
- Iterating through items of a `DOMNodeList` returns `DOMNode`'s ([DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php))

The actual items returned are not `DOMNodes` but `DOMElements` (which extends the former).

---

Using `var_dump()` or `print_r()` on these items still gives the (object value omitted) string, however this doesn't appear to be an error message.  The [DOMElements](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) have a method `getAttribute(string $name)` that you can call to get the attribute:

```
$html = new DOMDocument;
$html->loadHTML($file);
$headings = $html->getElementsByTagName('h2');
    foreach ($headings as $heading) {
            echo($heading->getAttribute('id'));
        }
```

This works and prints the IDs of all heading two tags.

Comment: This took me several hours to work out, I'm not sure if it was just my backwards interpretation of the documentation that caused the problem but posting to help anyone else in same situation